# Java: Finding an Integer in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, integer, min

**The Question:**
Create a static method called findElementIndex, which takes an integer and an integer array as input parameters, and returns the smallest index where that value appears. If the value is not in the array, the method should return -1.
  *Example:
value: 3   theArray:{10, 3, 6, 3, 8, 10} ==>  1
or  value: 10  theArray:{11, 3, 6, 7, 9, 60} ==> -1*

```
public static int findElementIndex (int value, int [ ] theArray) 
{  }
```

**My code:** Will not compile & I think i've looked at it too many times to notice a mistake.

```
int index = 0;
int n = -1;

for(int i =0; i < theArray.length; i++) 
    if(value == theArray[i]) {
        index = i; 
        return index; 
    }
    else {
        return n;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Step 1: Format your code readably. Step 2: Look closely at the helpful error the compiler is giving you.

Comment: What compile errors are you receiving?

Comment: You forgot to put braces around the body of your for-loop

Comment: @alfasin: *Technically*, he/she doesn't need them. I'd put them there, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder now it's easier to see that the code will always return on the first loop... :)

Comment: @Minty: You **changed** the code, you didn't just fix the formatting. It's not appropriate to change the code in the question unless you're doing something like moving content from a comment from the OP into the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you edit it in a way that the code is not changed and it's more readable? It's not letting me edit it now...

Comment: @Aify: At this point, I don't think there's any reason to bother, and as the code is completely invalid anyway, it would be tricky to reformat it without being misleading. Nor do I think the question is *remotely* worth the effort people are kindly putting into it.

Answer (score 0):

I put your code into Eclipse, and the compiler complains that the method must return a result of type int.

What the compiler says is wrong is that if your array is passed in with 0 length, your for loop will never go into the if statements, so you need an extra return statement outside the for loop.

The other logical error that your compiler won't complain about is that you used an else statement. That means that if the array is more than length 0, after the first test you will instantly quit the function and return either 0 or -1.

eg:

```
public static int findElementIndex(int value, int[] theArray) {
    int index = 0;
    int n = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
        if (value == theArray[i]) {
            index = i;
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1; // if the array was length 0, your for loop will not run.
}
```

Also, **please use proper brackets**.

Not having brackets is a very stupid idea.

You can accidentally write code like this, where you want to run the 3 `do this` lines inside the for loop:

```
for (condition)
    do this
    do this 2
    do this 3
```

but would actually mean

```
for (condition) { 
    do this 
}
do this 2
do this 3
```

which leaves out `do this 2` and `do this 3` - not what you were expecting. It's a pain to debug without brackets as well. If only you put the brackets in on the first shot.. you wouldn't even come to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static boolean inArray(int value, int[] array) {

    for (int arrayEntry : array) {
      if (value == arrayEntry) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have some odd code formatting, but you also are missing a key step - you only want to return -1 if you've finished going through all the values and didn't find it!  Also, you don't need to store values in a variable just to immediately return them!

Try this:

```
int index = 0;
for(int i =0; i < theArray.length; i++){
    if(value == theArray[i]) {
        return i; //returns where we found it if it matches
    }
}
return -1; //this line is only reached if we didn't already return
```

Comment: index will always be 0